# Getting multiple variables back from PHP file after ajaxSubmit or $.post method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Up to this moment I was using this types of methods to send some variables via Ajax to server side php file and bring back some answer.

```
$('#some_form').ajaxSubmit({
    success: function(result)
    {
        some code....
    }
});


$.post('serverside_script.php', { variable: 'value' },
    function(result) 
    {
        some code...
    });
```

Answer was always in 1 variable and it was ok till now.
But now I need several variables to come back from PHP side.
How can I modify my scripts to get several variables back ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "result" in the callback you have showed is all that you could get from PHP - this is the server side response. You could retun JSON from PHP - something like this:

```
$json = json_encode(array('content' => 'some html content to show on page', 'var2' => 'value2', 'var3' => 'value3'));
echo $json;
exit;
```

Probably you will then need to parse the JSON:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

```
$.post('serverside_script.php', { variable: 'value' }, function(result) 
{
    result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
    alert(result.content);
    alert(result.var2);
    alert(result.var3);
});
```

Comment: I edited my answer to show you the client-side usage of the JSON, as probably you will need that too.